# Sequentially Running through lists in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, iteration, sequence

How can I tell python to run through a list sequentially, running the same function (in this case searching for the bag with 'rice'), and if the bag with rice is not found, start from `bag1` again and begin searching every bag from bag1-bigbag2. My example:

```
import random
bag1 = "bag of chips"
bag2 = "bag of cookies"
bag3 = "bag of cheetos"
ricebag = "bag of rice"

baglist = [bag1, bag2, bag3, ricebag]
bigbag1 = random.choice(baglist)

bags =[bag1, bag2, bag3, bigbag1]
rice = False
while not rice:
    for bag in bags:
        if ' rice' in bag:
            print('rice found')
            rice = True
            break
print('yum')
```

End goal is to continue searching through the bags sequentially until the `if` statement is true. In a real example the `bags` represent urls in which I am parsing through, `rice` being the keyword I am searching for in the urls. The urls are changing so eventually `rice` will be uploaded to the url and the loop will break.

Comment: `random.choice[baglist]` => `random.choice(baglist)`

Comment: What is the point of starting the search from the beginning again, if it was not found the first time? Or am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: @PaulRooney I just made this example to make the reading simpler,  in my situation the bags will actually be urls that I want to monitor. Instead of making a different script to see if "rice" is in the xml of the url, I want to put it all in one script. Cycle through the urls until I get a hit

Comment: Is something not working in this script?  Also, if 'rice' is not found, won't it be an infinite loop?

Comment: @bozdoz No, eventually `bigbag1` or `bigbag2` will randomly select `ricebag` which will make the `if` statement true, breaking the loop and printing `yum` ... I just need to know how to continue searching through the bags until the if statement is true

Comment: no it wont because you only do the `random.choice` calls once, outside the loop so they will never add `ricebag` unless its done the first time. It sounds like a screwy algorithm choice. In theory even if it was in the loop it might never select `rice` or it might not for a very long time.

Comment: Well this is only a simulation, I am truly looking for a way to loop through the  `bags` until `rice` is found. Not trying to sound snotty but does that make sense?

Comment: I think we need to get to the root of the problem you are trying to solve. It sounds to me like you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If we can get past the issue with your solution and address the issue of your problem, we can get somewhere. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question, but nevertheless this is how you loop a number of lists over and over again:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

a = range(5)
b = range(10, 14)
c = range(100, 107)

for item in cycle(chain(a, b, c)):
    print item
```

This loops infinitely, but you can add your condition in a loop to break it eventually.